# How to get id elemnt

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I did ActionLink, which open the PartialView, but I need to put in this partialView the Id of clicked elemnt. How can I do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Below code will clear cache
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    //Below code will run the JQuery when document is ready.

        $(document).ready(function ()
        {//if you see that code in the partial view our submit button
            //is defined as .close class, so below code says on document ready
            //append click event to this button           
            $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
                //prevent default action on the button click
                e.preventDefault();
                //get value of name textbox id=Namecontact
                //put in variable name
                // HERE I WANT to get ID (see code below)
                var t = $("#idtable").val();
                var name = $("#Namecontact").val();
                //get value of email textbox id=emailcontact
                //put in variable email
                var email = $("#emailcontact").val();
                //get value of message textarea id=messagecontact
                //put it in variable message
                //note since messagecontact is a textarea
                //we need to use .text() rather than .val()
                var message = $("#messagecontact").text();
                //Start ajax call
                $.ajax({
                    //define method for sending data to controller
                    type: "POST",
                    //define controller URL
                    url: "/Home/ContactUs",
                    //define data to send to controller
                    //if you remember our controller accepts
                    //3 parameters name, email and message
                    data: { "name": name, "email": email, "message": message },
                    //create a success function
                    //this method is executed if controller
                    //defined by the URL is found
                    //and it accepts the data sent
                    //control comes to this point if the controller
                    //is executed. So data in function(data)
                    //contains the Json data we sent
                    //from the controller
                    success: function (data) {
                        //Now in the div with id result defined in
                        //index page previously we will put in the
                        //data. As you can see Json data is very 
                        //easy way of returning to ajax call because
                        //now you can simply say data(dot)variable sent
                        //and you will get the returned value.
                        $("#result").html("<ul><li>Name: " + data.nameret + "</li><li>Email: " + data.emailret + "</li><li>Message: " + data.messageret + "</li><li>Table: "+data.TableNumber+"</li></ul>");
                        //now close the modal dialog we opened
                        $(".dialog").dialog("close");
                    },
                    //control comes to this function if ajax doesn't
                    //find the controller or controller doesn't accepts
                    //the data sent or controller throws exception

                    error: function (data) {
                        //If it happens alert user of the error
                        alert("There was error processing this");
                        //close the modal dialog
                        $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
                    }
                });

            });
            //Below code will append a click event to the class openDialog
            //which we assigned to the anchor previously
            $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {

                var TableId = window.event.srcElement.id;
                //Below code will prevent default action from occuring
                //when openDialog anchor is clicked
                e.preventDefault();

                // Here I want to get Id of elemnt, and save it in elevent value 
                //idtable        
                $('#idtable').val('TableId');
                //This is the actual implementation of the dailog
                $("<div></div>")
                //To the div created for dialog we will add class named dialog
                //this is done so that we can refer to the dialog later
                //we will see this in a short while why it is important
                .addClass("dialog")
                //add attribute add id attribute
                //note id attribute is assigned the same value as data-dialog-id
                //attribute in openDialog anchor
                .attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id"))

                //below code appends this div to body
                .appendTo("body")
                //below code describes the attribute for the dialog
                .dialog({
                    //below code assigns title to the dialog
                    //here we use same title as data-dialog-title attribute
                    //in openDialog anchor tag
                    title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),

                    //this will append code to close the dialog
                    //and also put close cross(x) in dialog
                    //we press ESC key in keyboard will also close dialog
                    close: function () { $(this).remove() },
                    //below code defines that the dialog is modal dialog
                    modal: true
                })
                //below code says take href from openDialog anchor
                //which is /Home/ContactUs and load it to the modal dialog
                .load(this.href);
            });
        }           
    );
```

Or if you can advice another solution it would be great. I neew open modal window, wehere user can put some information, and after send me. But I want to know Id of element from which it was sended

Answer (score 1):

You can pass whatever you want to your partial view trough the action link like this:

View:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
      "test",          // linkText
      "myAction",      // actionName
      "MyController",  // controllerName
      new {                  // routeValues
           myID = Model.someID 
          },
     null  // htmlAttributes)
```

Controller:

```
 public PartialViewResult myAction(int myID)
    {             
         myData=//do whatever with your id   
        return PartialView(myData);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did as you said, but it didn't work. I got an error (POST http://localhost:3478/Home/ContactUs 500 (Internal Server Error) )

Answer (score 0):

My code in asp.net page

```
     @foreach (var item in Model)
       {

     @Html.ActionLink(" ", "ContactUs", "Home", new { myId = item.IdTable}, new { @class =               "openDialog", 
     data_dialog_id = "emailDialog", value = "1", data_dialog_title = "contactus",     @id = "_Logo" + item.IdTable })
      }
```

My controller

```
       public ActionResult ContactUs(int myId, string name,string email,string message)
     {    /*Your other processing logic will go here*/
         return Json(new
        {
         nameret=name,
           emailret=email,
            messageret=message
         },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: I got an error (POST localhost:3478/Home/ContactUs 500 (Internal Server Error) )

Comment: Hello sorry for the delay, How are you clicking this link if there is no text on it? I copy and paste your code to test this and I don't have any issue with this. I think the 500 error has nothing to do with this code, check this link to see if you can solve this problem http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/500servererror.htm